# Passing a method for later evaluation

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I pass a function as an argument, and the function is a jQuery method, will calling the passed function later still correctly set `this`? I thought it would, but calling the function later has `this = Window`.

Example code:

```
var $input = $('input').first();

var evaluators = [];

evaluators.push($input.val);

_.forEach(evaluators, function(valueMethod) {
    return valueMethod() //returns undefined always since this = window
}).
```

Comment: Do you mean `$input.val`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

```
evaluators.push($input.val.bind($input));
```

It is worth noting `bind` is [not supported on older browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/) (e.g. IE8 and FF3 (or older)).

Comment: That is what I was expecting to have to do. Does that mean JS only sets `this` properly if you call the function directly from the object instance like `obj.prototypeMethod()`?

Comment: You are right, I have added a link to a compatibility table

Comment: That is correct. Basically, what `input.val` refers to is the function itself, without it's context (e.g. the prototype method). The context is passed when you make the call. What `bind` does is create a new function which wraps around the original one, defining the context passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [jQuery.proxy()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to see how context or `this` of the function can be set.