# Passing prototype methods

Tags: javascript, prototype

Yesterday, I asked this question: [Passing a method for later evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851241/passing-a-method-for-later-evaluation) and thought that it was as simple as passing a prototype method, rather than calling it immediately after access, resets `this` to `Window`. However, today I came across this code today:

```
sSharing.shareFileWithGroup( node, groupId,  d.resolve, d.reject ); //d is a Angular promise
```

and when shareFileWithGroup calls its 3rd or 4th argument in its body, it correctly calls any functions previously passed to `d.then`, i.e. the passed method can locate the original object it was accessed from. What exactly are the rules for setting `this` when calling a prototype method? The two situations seem to be inconsistent.

EDIT: My understanding is that the passed method `d.resolve/reject` should not be able to call then functions previously passed as arguments to `.then`, but it does. My question is how it does it? The only thing I can think of is if promises are built into JS or the methods aren't actually using the prototype and are being put in the constructed object directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: That link implies that the passed promise method won't be able to call then `.then` function arguments, which the answer from my previous question did too. Edited my question to make it clearer what I'm confused about.

Comment: *"What exactly are the rules for setting `this` when calling a prototype method?"* There are no special rules. What `this` refers to depends on how the function is called. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this .

Comment: Please see my edit. How is the Promise properly being resolved when only it's prototype method is passed in? It shouldn't have `this` set properly and have no memory of which promise it was accessed from originally.

Comment: What makes you think `d.resolve` comes from the prototype? What does `d.hasOwnProperty('resolve')` say?

Comment: Chrome console showed only `d = Deferred {promise: Promise}` next to the variable (Idk why I thought it showed function properties) and I looked up the source code before thinking of your solution, but accidentally looked at the Promise constructor, not the Deferred constructor (which has similar methods and uses a prototype). But you are right, and Deferred puts methods directly in the object. If you say as much in a comment I'll mark it correct.